# Pandas - combine two lines into one (simplify)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lines of code that I want to simplify into one:

```
df1 = df[df.column1.isin(values) == False]
df2 = df1[df1.column2.isin(values) == False]
```

Preferably, I don't want to have to create df2 at all.

Comment: Do you think Preferably, I don't want to have to create `df1` at all. ?

Comment: Thanks for your help! why use '''df2''' instead of '''df1'''?

Comment: Because final Dataframe is `df2`, `df1` is temporary DataFrame in question.

Answer (score 4):

For avoid `df1` chain both conditions by `&` for bitwise `AND`, instead compare by `False` invert mask by `~`:

```
df2 = df[~df.column1.isin(values) & ~df.column2.isin(values)]
```